Wordpress: Something is prepending content to document body response
I am trying to help my mom with her website, however I am not familiar with Wordpress and the ecosystem around it.
What I noticed is that Facebook is not scraping a page correctly which lead me to inspect the page and notice a strange <div> elemen before the <!DOCTYPE html> declaration.
The div contains a bunch of random links.
So my question is - what might be the reason that those links get prepended to the html response? What in the Wordpress ecosystem is able to add in those? I am also assuming that there could be a malicious intent on the hosting side of things - from whoever owns the hosting.
I inspected the wordpress code and the theme code, but wasn't able to find anything that would add code even before the <!DOCTYPE html> declaration.
I have access to the admin user on wordpress and to a cpanel, which aside from File Browser and DB I haven't used much before.
Any help is appreciated.
Sample article (it's in Bulgarian but that should be irrelevant):
This is the div I see at the top of the page:

<div style="display:none">
    <a href="https://blog.routelink.net.id/wp-includes/js/uploads/">situs zeus379</a>
    <a href="https://gugustugas.riau.go.id/depan/images/thailand/"slot thailand</a>
    <a href="https://ketapang.serdangbedagaikab.go.id/wp-includes/js/thai/">slot server thailand</a>
    <a href="https://www.ust.ac.id/wp-includes/js/qris/">slot qris</a>
    <a href="https://dekranasda.solokkab.go.id/assetsBeranda/scss/uploads/?level=zeus379">https://dekranasda.solokkab.go.id/assetsBeranda/scss/uploads/?level=zeus379</a>
    <a href="https://puskesmas-jati.kuduskab.go.id/wp-includes/js/uploads/">slot gacor maxwin</a>
    <a href="https://simbok.anambaskab.go.id/storage/post/uploads/">zeus379</a>
    <a href="https://gugustugas.riau.go.id/uploads/jepang/">slot jepang</a>
    <a href="https://bappeda.sintang.go.id/wp-content/upgrade/">slot server jepang</a>
    <a href="https://ketapang.serdangbedagaikab.go.id/wp-content/upgrade/demo/">slot demo</a>
    <a href="https://gugustugas.riau.go.id/js/dana/">slot dana</a>
    <a href="https://gugustugas.riau.go.id/depan/js/sgacor/">slot gacor</a>
    <a href="https://bappeda.sintang.go.id/wp-content/plugins/demo/">demo slot</a>
    <a href="https://jurnal.unisa.ac.id/files/uploads/">slot maxwin</a>
    <a href="https://gugustugas.riau.go.id/depan/uploads/">slot gacor 4d</a>
</div>


Those are clearly "spam" links, so your system likely has been infected with something. "there could be a malicious intent on the hosting side of things" - that is probably rather unlikely, more often these kind of "attacks" are performed using WordPress itself - by exploiting security flaws in an outdated core WP, or one of the plugins.

Do you think if I check the code for all plugins I can find a reference to whatever injects this code into the website?
I am not even sure what to look for, but maybe I can start disabling plugins and see when one stops doing it.
Thanks for the help!

Can't really say. A vulnerable plugin might just have been used as the attack vector - but that doesn't mean the code of the plugin itself was modified afterwards, it might as well be that some flaw was exploited to create a new script file somewhere on the server, and get that included in the whole WP process somehow.  Searching for any of the added content you see, might not give any results - the code used in such attacks is usually "obfuscated." Checking across all files, if you find an eval statement anywhere, might be a good start though.

There's guides available how to deal with an infected WP, do a bit of research to find one, and follow its instructions.
